# How to get the button's id value with my js?

Tags: javascript, events

A simple html structure.

```
<button id="b1">b1</button>
<button id="b2">b2</button>
<button id="b3">b3</button>
```

Add  event listener to buttons.

```
 var bs = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
 for(var i = 0; i < bs.length; i++){
   bs[i].addEventListener("click", getInfo);
 }
```

How to write getInfo function to output button's id when clicked?

```
function getInfo() {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one thing you need to do is to pass the event value to your getInfo functoin.

There's an example below:

```js
var  bs = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for(var i=0;i<bs.length;i++){
  bs[i].addEventListener("click",getInfo);
}
function getInfo(e){
  alert(e.target.id);
}
```

```html
<button id="b1" >b1</button>
<button id="b2" >b2</button>
<button id="b3" >b3</button>
```